# Comparing algorithmic complexities

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

If an algorithm has a running time  $ T(n) = O(n$ log $n)$, would it be possible to show that $T(n) = o(n^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

$$
T(n)=O(n\log(n))\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T(n)}{n\log(n)}=c\in\mathbb{R}\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T(n)}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T(n)}{n\log(n)}\frac{\log(n)}{n}=c*0=0\implies T(n)=o(n^2)
$$